.css and .js was blocked due to MIME type mismatch
My HTML is being rendered as a string.

This is how I set my headers.
@app.after_request
def apply_caching(response):
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/*"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers["Content-Security-Policy"] =  'default-src https:'
    response.headers["Expires"] = 'Thu, 01 Dec 2024 16:00:00 GMT'
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'includeSubDomains; max-age=63072000'
    response.headers["X-Content-Type-Options"] = "nosniff"
    return response

How do I get it to render? I've tried "application/json" "application/javascript" "/" "text/html" and "text/html; charset=utf-8" and I'm not sure what to try otherwise.
I am using Flask to render the template.
@app.route("/")
def render():
  return render_template('index.html') 


HTML should have the header text/html; charset=utf-8. You should not be setting the response headers for Content-Type for every single request though, as your app also returns javascript files and CSS. Just get rid of the line that sets the response header for Content-Type and it should work.
@app.after_request
def apply_caching(response):
    # ↓ delete this line ↓
    # response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/*"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers["Content-Security-Policy"] =  'default-src https:'
    response.headers["Expires"] = 'Thu, 01 Dec 2024 16:00:00 GMT'
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'includeSubDomains; max-age=63072000'
    response.headers["X-Content-Type-Options"] = "nosniff"
    return response


It didn't work. Please see my edit on the question for a screenshot.

Please edit your question to add the code for setting the headers.

I edited the question with the information. Thanks

Okay, I edited my answer.
